# Error handled by both express and process.on('uncaughtException) in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a problem with an error appearing on one of my express route. I handled it by using express `next` but then the error is also caught by my global `process.on('uncaughtException')` that is implemented to shut-down my server. Hope this example is clear.

```
app.get("/api/users", async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            // (1) This call will throw an error
            const users = await getUsers()
            res.send(users)
        }
        catch (err) {
            //  (2) The error will be correctly caught by this try catch and send to the error handler
            next(err)
        }
    })

// (3) The problem is that it will be also caught by this and my server will stop
// I don't want this since I've already handled it using express
process.on('uncaughtException', (err: Error) => cleanShutdown(`Uncaught exception`, err))
```

Is it possible to avoid going to (3) when I have already handled the error?

Comment: Have you tried just doing next(). It should theoretically ignore the error as it has already been caught

Comment: can you show your global express error handler?

Comment: Well, you could stop calling `next(err)` and instead just do something like `res.sendStatus(500)` and not call `next()` at all.  But, if you're really get an `uncaughtException`, I suspect it's coming from something other than the code you show because this code shouldn't be doing that.  Perhaps `getUsers()` has a problem in its implementation.  Can you show us that code?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the responses. So according to what you all are saying it seems that it shouldn't behave like this? Once the error reaches the express handler it shouldn't go to the `process.on('uncaughtException',...)` If that is the case I would like to check again the 'getUsers()' function.